# How to tag a question on this site (properly)?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[Multiple robots in ROS Gazebo SITL with separate MAVlink/MAVproxy software codes](http://answers.ros.org/question/246116/multiple-robots-in-ros-gazebo-sitl-with-separate-mavlinkmavproxy-software-codes/) is the original question which isn't having proper tags; Commas are not accepted while tagging and re-tagging apparently requires [100 to 500 Karma points](http://answers.ros.org/question/9054/can-i-add-tags-to-an-existing-question/); Unfortunately, I was able to tag just one tag and all other tags require "number, characters or -+.#" (something that I have been unable to understand).

I have spent about an hour on this and I would like to set the tags for the question as "gazebo .ros mav quadcopter .launch .world mavconn SITL roslaunch multi-agent". Can you please let me know if that is possible? (What am I doing wrong while tagging?)

Thanks for your time and consideration.

Prasad N R

**Appended information:** Trying "1gazebo 2.ros 3mav 4quadcopter 5.launch 6.world 7mavconn 8SITL 9roslaunch 10multiagent" resulted in '1gazebo', '2.ros', '3mav', '4quadcopter', '5.launch', '6.world', '7mavconn', '8SITL', '9roslaunch' and '10multi-agent' tags (with numbers). Trying commas with spaces like "gazebo, .ros, mav, quadcopter, .launch, .world, mavconn, SITL, roslaunch, multi-agent" didn't work out either. Other similar attempts like "gazebo -+.# .ros -+.# mav -+.# quadcopter -+.# .launch -+.# .world -+.# mavconn -+.# SITL -+.# roslaunch -+.# multi-agent" didn't work out.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246147/how-to-tag-a-question-on-this-site-(properly)?/) by [PrasadNR](https://answers.ros.org/users/28296/prasadnr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2016-10-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've just retagged your question for you.

Not sure, but it would appear that the dots (`.`) before `ros`, `launch` and `world` did not make it through the filter and causes your tags to not be updated.

If you feel the explanation of what are acceptable tags is confusing, please open an issue over at [ros-infrastructure/answers.ros.org](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/answers.ros.org/issues).

---

Edit: not sure what you are trying to achieve. Adding numbers does not make sense.

Tags are simply single words, separated by spaces. No need for commas or numbers. And please: this is not Twitter: no hashes.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-10-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2